# Can you burn .img files meant for USB drives to a DVD or CD and still expect it to boot?

Tags: burning

I want to install Guix on one of my old computers, the place where I downloaded them is right [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/) and its supposed to be on flashed on USB drives, but I'm wondering if I could burn it to a CD or DVD.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, yes.

Find the cd/dvd device using `lsblk` usually something like `/dev/sr0`

`cd` to the directory with the .img.gz file

and

```
gzip -d gnu-system-demo-0.4.img.gz
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=gnu-system-demo-0.4.img
```

or

```
unxz gnu-usb-install-0.7.x86_64.xz
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=gnu-usb-install-0.8.x86_64-linux
```

## update

```
bob@bob-p7-1298c:~/Downloads$ fdisk -l gnu-usb-install-0.8.x86_64-linux 

Disk gnu-usb-install-0.8.x86_64-linux: 838 MB, 838860800 bytes
89 heads, 52 sectors/track, 354 cylinders, total 1638400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c70ee

                           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
gnu-usb-install-0.8.x86_64-linux1   *        2048     1628160      813056+  83  Linux
```

We can see that the file system starts at sector `2048`

Each sector being 512 bytes, we can give an offset.

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=1048576 gnu-usb-install-0.8.x86_64-linux /mnt
```

And then copy the contents of `/mnt` to the network boot folder.

Giving pxelinux.0 the requisite vmlinuz and initrd locations? Although I am not exactly sure about the details of guix. It is also possible to boot directly from an iso image... but that would require memdisk, and making the iso image.

Comment: Do you mean for all the images, or just the gnu-system-demo?

Comment: @toxemicsquire Right. It should also work for the other images as well. They look to be the raw images. And after looking around on how GUIX suggests to install... they say use `dd` to write to usb. You are asking about CD/DVDs and to do that you can use `wodim` (CDs) or `growisofs` (DVDs/bluray) to write an image to a disk. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/html_node/System-Installation.html

Comment: Wait, is it possible to PXE with it too?

Comment: @toxemicsquire I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Not sure if this is still relevant to you, but I'll post a reliable solution for others:

The most reliable way I've found of doing is to use gnome-disks.

Open the program, select the flash drive, and in the top right settings icon, select "Restore Disk Image" (make sure to select the one on top which uses the entire disk, not just restoring a single partition).

Most likely, you will have a large sector of free space left after the operation, best keep that as it is in case you need it during your GuixSD installation to modify the config.scm file.

This works 100% of the time for me, no need to use any terminal commands. gnome-disks seems able to program MBR for flash drives.

Keep in mind, this will delete ALL data on that drive!

Comment: one alternative is unetbootin, but it sometimes doesn't boot (it might even be deprecated at this point). theres another program cant remember the name, it would attempt to create its own grub config in order to allow multiple bootable os's...never worked for me